# No animation with CSS keyframe (Mozilla Firefox)

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe, web-animations

I'm trying to learn CSS. I tried to do a simple animation: changing the background color of a span by using keyframes, but nothing change/animate

My code looks like this :

HTML :

```
    <span class="brand1">Test</span>
```

CSS :

```
`body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;}

.brand1{
     display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 10vw;
    -moz-animation: test, 2s, infinite;
    animation: test, 2s, infinite;

}
#header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: teal;
}

@keyframes test{
    from {background-color: tomato; }
    to { background-color: violet; }
}

@-moz-keyframes test{
    from {background-color: tomato; }
    to { background-color: violet; }
}`
```

I use Mozilla, so I think that there shouldn't be any compatibility issues. So where is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Because you have put **commas** in animation property, we need to separate property methods by using **space** and not by commas.

2) If you want to change the color of text you use **color** property which is used to change the color of fonts and not the **background-color** property it will change the background color of your webpage.

Here is the code I have made changes to it. You can have a look.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;}

.brand1{
     display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 10vw;
    animation: test 1s infinite;

}


@keyframes test{
    from {color: tomato; }
  to { color: violet; }
}
```

```html
 <span class="brand1">Test</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The animation of your `.brand1` is not correctly written, you need to separate the duration and the animation.

Here a sample with the way you need to do it

```
p {
   animation-duration: 25s;
   animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {
   from {
       margin-left: 100%;
       width: 300%;
   }
   75% {
       font-size: 300%;
       margin-left: 25%;
       width: 150%;
   }

   to {
       margin-left: 0%;
       width: 100%;
   }
}
```

Here your code modified for this way

```
.brand1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 10vw;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation: test;
}


@keyframes test {
    from {color: tomato; }
    to { color: violet; }
}
```